# Refresh Angular4 components after save

Tags: angular

I'm trying to refresh the components in my Angular 4 site.
I've put

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="nostore" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1" />
```

in the index.html, so now when I make a change and save the index.html file, refreshing the browser shows the changes to index.html in the browser.

If I change and save any of the component .html files (or .ts/.js files) then the hit refresh, the related component isn't updated in the browser.   Disabling the browser's cache forces any changes to be shown, but that also affects every site I visit.

Any idea how to update a component without disabling the cache in the browser?
Thanks

**Edit**
Forcing a refresh with Ctrl+F5 doesn't force a refresh of the component, just the .html page itself.

Comment: Would you mind to check this [website](https://csjdpw.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/~Genhan.Chen/pages/43393408/Angular+2+browser+cache+cleaning+issue)..

Comment: That'll be good for forcing an update for the production environment but I don't want to have to edit a number each time I save a page.

Comment: If you are using @angular/cli you can just start your app with `ng serve` - that will monitor all of your files for changes (including css files) and refresh your browser....or are you using that and it isn't working?

Comment: I haven't used that.   I'm following the Angular Tour of Heroes tutorial on https://angular.io/tutorial which I worked through using Visual Studio Code to create and which worked as expected, refreshing the browser refreshes the component.   I couldn't get debugging to work in VSCode so transferred the sample into VS Enterprise (as that's what I'll be using for the other parts of the project)    It's only in VSE that the refreshing isn't being forced.   Have you got a link to a site about ng serve that's any good for a beginner ? ;)